# Update to Homework Policy 2018

Tags: discussion, homework, site-policy

As a follow up to the post made by my fellow moderator ubiquitous
[Homework questions with scans of notes/exam papers](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1885/homework-questions-with-scans-of-notes-exam-papers)

An additional stanza will be added to our site's [homework policy](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1465/economics-se-policy-on-homework-questions). however some details need to be worked out.

the following has been added:

> The user must demonstrate his homework question and effort using text, markdown syntax and/or images space provided in the text of his question submission for the site.
>
> We will not accept pictures of work done in notebooks as demonstrated effort as these images are non-searchable and do not contribute to the betterment of the site.

Updates to [Generic response to Homework Questions](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1771/generic-response-to-homework-questions) will be added to provide tools for users and moderators to help enforce site policy.

Comment: A needed change lol, we out here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is unclear, and unnecessarily gendered.

> The user must demonstrate his homework question and effort using text, markdown syntax and/or images space provided in the text of his question submission for the site.

This will come as a shock to some, but we do have some female users. And you really need to be much less ambiguous, and much more straightforward, for new users to understand what it is we're asking of them.

How about something like:

> Do not merely post a scan or image of the whole question, nor of your attempted answer. Enter your question, and the work you've done to try to answer it, as text. You can use Markdown[*link to markdown help*] and Mathjax[*link to mathjax help*] to make it more readable. If the question requires images (for example, a chart), post those as images, but enter the question text as text.

Comment: Valid. updating policy to your version now.

Comment: Although I agree on the gender comment IMHO " This will come as a shock to some, but we do have some female users. " is unnessecary. In fact it may be plain wrong. We may have more than just "some" female users. I really don't think there is a way of telling, and quite frankly the numbers shouldn't matter as such. What matters is not to fall down to Econ job rumor level in terms of gender and sexism.