# Homework questions with effort by someone other than the poster

Tags: discussion

This is a continuation of [Homework questions with scans of notes/exam papers](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1885/homework-questions-with-scans-of-notes-exam-papers).

Was I correct to approve the following edit, in which a user (not the OP) converts the scanned images into Mathjax?

https://economics.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/14513

(Perhaps you can only follow the link if your reputation score is high enough. Sorry for the exclusion.)

Do we require searchability only or also the effort that goes into typing up your scribbles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strictly speaking based on our current policy we just require that effort be typed up and marked down properly.

The gains that come with searchability should follow.

Answer (score 3):

Effort has two components:

1. taking the time to write the question up properly (i.e. no scans!). This can be done by anyone with the same effect namely, that the post is easily readable, searchable, and shows a minimum level of respect for the reader.
2. taking the time to at least try and solve the problem yourself so that this site is not used as a homework completion service (which we know to be bad for a student's long-run educational outcomes). This can only be done by the poster themselves.

The post in question falls into category 1, so I think you did the right thing.

Comment: Okay, even though I have posted my question that holds these two competents you stressed, I don’t get any answer. I think this website is totally useless. For example, https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/22026/market-clearing-condition-with-walras-law